# Define, Knockoutjs, "text!"

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm watching 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I1USsIW8aWE

@25:12 you'll see something like this on the screen. I'm trying to build out something that works like what he has, though I have no idea what this "text! ./programme" thing is going on. It looks like a relative file path syntax that I've never seen before. Is that Knockout? Is it something to do with js? I'm using visual studio, can I use a different way to get at the file path another way?

Also, I'm getting an error that says define is undefined. I'm not really sure how to use define, or what it's doing. Any good reading on that? I know it has something to do with AMD, what I don't know Is it part of another library, or is it built into JS?

```
define(['knockout', 'text!./test.html'], function (ko, templateMarkup) {
function test(params) {
    this.message = ko.observable('thingy');
    }

    return {
        viewModel: test,
        template: templateMarkup
    };
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly, but I found this: https://github.com/requirejs/text

Comment: Ah, I was missing the text part of require. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That appears to be the requirejs text plugin.

https://github.com/requirejs/text

Comment: I had require, was missing the text part of it. Thanks!